# What should distance be between the two lower cabinets flanking a "30" inch range?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, stove

What should the proper distance be between lower cabinets flanking a "30" inch kitchen range?  We have researched this subject and find more then one answer.   Some say 30 inches, others say 30 1/4 inches in case the range is not 'square'.  Is this ever a real issue?  We want to minimize the gap so food crumbs have less chance of dropping onto floor between cabinet and range, but are we 'taking a risk' of a tight fit by making the gap only 30 inches (the range is 29 7/8)?

Comment: Make sure you measure the distance between the lower cabinets at the front, back, and middle as well, to make sure that they all agree.  This may be where the 'not square' thought comes through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the range is not square?  Huh?  Don't hire the person that said this! Ranges come in standard sizes, and as you see, your 30" range is NOT 30".  The standard is to set the space between the base cabinets is 30"

Comment: +1 See typical installation instructions calling for spacing of 29 15/16 to 30 1/16. [Sample](http://products.geappliances.com/MarketingObjectRetrieval/Dispatcher?RequestType=PDF&Name=31-10867.pdf)

Comment: I have a range that is not square and was not when brand new. Perhaps it was twisted I'm transit or something, shrug.